# Observable.create is never called during tests when using the looper's scheduler

Tags: java, android, testing, rx-java, robolectric

I have been working on this issue for some time now
This is the code I am testing

```
public Observable<Void> prepare() {
        return Observable.<Void>create(subscriber -> {  
           // Some work is being done here but this part is never reached
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }).subscribeOn(scheduler);
}
```

The scheduler is the looper's scheduler (the class inherits from HandlerThread)

The test I am writing is as follows:

```
@Test
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    TestSubscriber<Void> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    subject.start();
    Observable<Void> obs = subject.prepare();
    obs.subscribe(testSubscriber);
    testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //assertions go here
    subject.quit();
}
```

The problem is the code in the Observable.create is never reached and the testSubscriber's timeout is always hit.
I've checked that the looper runs and that the scheduler exists. It works well when I run the app. I am using RobolectricTestRunner.
Any ideas why the code is never reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer.
This is how my test looks now:

```
    @Test
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        TestSubscriber<Void> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
        subject.start();
        Observable<Void> obs = subject.prepare();
        obs.subscribe(testSubscriber);
        shadowOf(subject.getLooper()).getScheduler().advanceToNextPostedRunnable();
        testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //assertion go here
        subject.quit();
    }
```

The problem I had is that Robolectric shadows the looper class and thus runnables that were queued there were never called.
In order to solve this I interacted with the shadow class and got it to run the Observable.create. I tried it before but I did it before I called subscribe and it must be called afterwards. [This helped me understand that](https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a).
Now it works fine. Thanks to all who tried.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler used in production code:

```
.subscribeOn(scheduler)
```

and scheduler used in test:

```
obs.subscribe(testSubscriber)
```

Are not the same. Please make your Presenter (or whatever holds prepare() method) to obtain scheduler. Than in production code pass your normal scheduler and in tests your TestSchubscriber.